Jpql Query using not like for inet
Hello I have a query where I want to filter the ips ending in 2. For that I wrote the NamedQuery as such:
@NamedQuery(name.., query="  ... AND c.ip NOT LIKE. '%2'")
When I run the above query in the app using createNamedQuery(...) I get the following error:
ERROR: operator does not exist:  inet ~~ character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

If I use cast(c.ip as string) then this error appears:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "string" does not exist

But this doesn't work even if for c entity ip is a String, but in database it is a column of type inet. I tried using cast with as string but it says that PSQL doesn't support data type string. Is there any other way to filter those ips using jpql?
I usually used a bitwise operation but now because I need a list I can not use a normal SQL and JPQL doesn't support bitwise operations
